# changing the reactive data for one template redraws the whole page

Tags: meteor

I have a page with two templates one template with a toolbar and the second with the rest of the page.

The buttons in the toolbar are displayed in their enabled or disabled form depending on a Session variable. This is one entry from the toolbar:

```
          {{#if canValidate}}
             <img id="validateForm" class="img-rounded" src="/images/nav/form_green.gif" style="height:32px; width: 32px"/>
          {{else}}
             <img id="validateFormDisabled" class="img-rounded" src="/images/nav/form_green_disabled.gif" style="height:32px; width: 32px"/>
          {{/if}}
```

the `canValidate` function is quite simple:

```
Template.formData.canValidate = function () {
   var states = Session.get("selected-form").states;
   return Session.get("selected-data-valid") && userHasPermission('validate') && Session.get("selected-data").state != states[states.length - 1].techName ;
}
```

whenever the value of `selected-data-valid` changes, the whole page is redrawn. How can I make Meteor redraw only the toolbar.

thank you for your support

Micha Roon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move this part to a new template or wrap it with `{{#isolate}}{{/isolate}}`